# shortcut to add throws declaration in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using eclipse for quite a while, but for last year or so I am trying to get used to Intellij Idea because that is what they use at my current workplace.

One feature I can not find a substitute in Idea is ability of eclipse to add throws declarations. In Eclipse I could right click on a underlined string and select "Add throws declaration" which then adds it to my method signature, but I can't find it for life of me in Idea. Is there such a functionality in Idea?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

When a piece of code needs error handling, IntelliJ underlines it with red. Set your pointer on that piece of code and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. IntelliJ should now give you the choice to either surround it with try/catch, add a catch clause, or to add a throws declaration.

In your case: click the underlined code → <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> → `Add Exception to Method Signature`

IntelliJ also has a shortcut to place your cursor on the next error or warning: <kbd>F2</kbd>. This – especially in combination with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> – is quite useful.

Comment: Is it possible that IntelliJ won't underline the code that needs error handling? If yes, then how to turn it on again?

Comment: For anyone using a different set of key bindings, the action for this is called "Show Intention Actions".

Answer (score 2):

On Mac it is Alt+Enter as well but you have to be at the end of the red line that shows that you have to handle the exception.

Comment: This is not true on my Mac